# Change image onLoad() - Where is my failure?

Tags: javascript

I want to change a image after my page is loaded. I wrote a Java Script file but I don't know where my error is.. I also don't get an error in the console...

JavaScript:

```
function changeImage(){
    changeImage = document.getElementsByClass("carousel-indicators");
    changeImage = changeImage.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;

    actualImage = document.getElementsByClass("item active");
    actualImage = actualImage.getElementsByClass("img-wrapper-inner");
    actualImage.getElementsByTagName("img").src = changeImage;
}
```

I also call the function with:

```
<img onload="changeImage()">
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: For one thing, it's `document.getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementsByClass`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I'm guessing that your `changeImage` function isn't being called. If you put a `console.log` in it, does it show up in the console?

Comment: @qxz means that the method `Document.getElementsByClass` does not exist. You can find the documentation on `Document.getElementsByClassName` on mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: I just typed into my `changeImage()` function now `alert("Worked!");` - But I do not get a alert... So at least my function isn't called... But why?

I say `<img onload="changeImage()">`

Comment: Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us your complete code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: https://gamekeys-shop.de/produkt/battlefield-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As qxz pointed out you're probably looking for the [`Document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method.

Furthermore using the same variable name as your method name and not using `var` to declare new variable may lead to unexpected results. As JavaScript has no problem in overriding your scope.

Last but not least, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Not a single HTMLElement. You should retrieve an element from the array to manipulate. Instead of trying to change the src field of the array.

So combining these items would give you some code like:

```js
function handleImageLoad() {
  var loadedImage = document.getElementsByClassName('loadableImage')[0].src;
  document
      .getElementsByClassName('loadState')[0]
      .innerHTML = 'Loaded image: ' + loadedImage;
}
```

```html
<img class="loadableImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" onload="handleImageLoad()" />
<p class="loadState">Loading...</p>
```

Comment: I changed it, look my link above, but it is still not working... Where is the problem...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to dive into your website to debug your code. Try adding a new section to your original question with an updated sample of your code. Better even, create a snippet like the one in my answer.

Comment: I fixed it! :D.

Comment: That's great to hear! Maybe you can share your change which lead to the fix, so others may be helped as well in the future. And most of all, best of luck with your webshop ;)